# How to bind to the result of a function in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I have an array of items that I want to keep track of across several controllers.  So, to do this, I made a service.

The service is basic for now, just adding items to an array and the ability to get the count:

```
angular.module('myapp.itemManagementService', [])
  .factory('myappItemSrv', [function () {
      var allItems = [];

      return {
          addItem: function (item) {
              allItems.push(item);
          },
          getItemCount: function () {
              return allItems.length;
          }
      };
  } ])
;
```

In my controller, I have a button that calls the addItem function and it is working fine, but I don't know how to bind the getItemCount so that the view auto-updates every time I add an item

In my controller, I have this:

```
$scope.count = myappItemSrv.getItemCount();
```

And then in the view

```
{{count}}
```

This only changes when I navigate away from the page, and then back

I realize that I am returning a value of a function and that won't bind, but I have no idea how to make this auto-update.  I tried wrapping the call to addItem in a `$scope.$apply` call, but the error I get is:

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getItemCount()` is invoked once, when the controller is loaded. One way to do this is to put it on the scope...

```
$scope.getItemCount = myappItemSrv.getItemCount;
```

And change the binding...

```
{{ getItemCount() }}
```